# WPF Update UI from DataTable through Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I followed MSDN's [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx) on Threading, Dispatcher, etc. for a WPF project I am doing. 
But I cannot get the UI to update. The only thing that I am doing differently, is I am updating a DataTable, and binding that DataTable to my XAML.

Here is the code behind:

```
Sub Approve_Click(obj As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    btnApprove.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, New ApproveDelegate(AddressOf ApproveThread))
End Sub

Sub ApproveThread()
    Dim Invoice_Model As New COGENT_Model.Invoice_Model
    For Each row In dt.Rows
        If row("check") = True Then
            Try
                '//calling db functions here...
                row("status") = 1
            Catch ex As Exception
                row("message") = ex.Message
                row("status") = 2
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvApprove" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Name="IsReadImage" Source="../Images/Status/statusNone.png"/>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="1">
                                        <Setter TargetName="IsReadImage" Property="Source" Value="../Images/Status/statusApproved.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="2">
                                        <Setter TargetName="IsReadImage" Property="Source" Value="../Images/Status/statusCanceled.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding check}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name_full}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding status}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding message}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

On the Window Load I am applying ItemSource Property. And this code in general works, does everything I need, but doesn't update the UI until its all done.

Quick explanation: I basically want a green image if its approved and a red image if something went wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI is single-threaded, and all your code runs from the UI thread -- hence it blocks the UI until complete.  To get the behavior you want, you need to spawn a background thread for "ApproveThread", and dispatch the row-value updates back to the UI thread.

C# example:

```
void Approve_Click(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(ApproveThread));
}

void ApproveThread() 
{
    var Invoice_Model = new COGENT_Model.Invoice_Model();
    foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row["check"])
        {
            try
            {
                '//calling db functions here...
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
                    row["status"] = 1
                ));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                    row["message"] = ex.Message;
                    row["status"] = 2;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3524375 ah sorry, I would, but I'm not expert enough in VB to pull it off.  I can add a C# example though if you're interested?

Comment: Absolutely! Any help you can give  would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user3524375 edited above.  I used `Task.Factory.StartNew` for the thread, but you could use `BackgroundWorker` or just `Thread` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I gave McGarnagle the correct answer as he was right on the mark. But for all those VB coders out there, common converters would not convert the code correctly:

for example, in the dispatcher i got:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action()(InlineAssignHelper(row("status"), 1)))
```

But the InlineAssignHelper wouldn't not work.
So after a little bit more searching (and if you are using .Net 4+), you can simply do this:

```
/to call the thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() DoBackgroundWork())

/to update the UI.
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() txtBox1.Text = "End")
```

Found the VB solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109424/how-to-make-dispatcher-begininvoke-run-in-background-in-vb-net)...